# Kmeans simple scrip

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I have a script, overall I understand the meaning but the last line, the output, can somebody explain why 0.5?

```
data = load('dataset_seeds.txt');
data = data(:,1:7);
K = 3;
[m,C,sumd,D] = kmeans(data,K);
display('CENTROID');
C
display('     IDX |JARAK KE C1|JARAK KE C2|JARAK KE C3');
[m D.^0.5]
```

Comment: You should ask whoever wrote the script why 0.5. Baffles me. [`D` is the distance from each point to each centroid.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html#buefs04-D) Maybe the author thought it’s the square distance?

Comment: @CrisLuengo since k-means *only* uses *squared* errors, yes, it is a squared distance.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: Do you have a reference for that? The documentation of `kmeans` just says "distance" not "squared Euclidean distance". There are many different error norms described in the literature for kmeans, not "*only squared* errors".

Comment: Lots of people misbelieve this. But the **mean** optimizes the squared errors. It does not optimize the absolute errors. Therefore, k-means cannot optimize non-squared Euclidean distances. q.e.d. also, that is why PAM, k-medians, k-medoids have been invented...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: We're talking about the `kmeans` function in MATLAB, which does implement different distance measures and different ways of computing the class centroids. Also, your argument is odd, since the partitioning of the space you obtain using Euclidean distances or squared Euclidean distances are identical. If people use squared Euclidean distances in the computation of k-means, it is not because they use the mean to compute the centroids, it's because it leads to the same result as the Euclidean distance and costs less.

Comment: Go read a book on KMeans. It's a two step algorithm. You ignore the "mean". The mean does not minimize Euclidean distances. Ever heard of "least squares", L2, etc.? And you can find dozens of threads on this, with obvious counterexamples.

Comment: Using it with the wrong distance -usually- won't explode your computer. All the supported distances of Matlab should converge. The cluster center will just not be the optimal cluster center, because the mean is not optimal for Manhattan distance, for example. K-medians will find better solutions.

Comment: So here is the counterexample for you: the cluster with 1d points 1, 1, 10. The mean is 4, which yields euclidean distances 3+3+6=12. Squared distances are 9+9+36=54. Now consider the center 1 instead. It has distances 0+0+9, so it is a much better cluster center for non-squared distances. Squared distances are 100. The mean is optimal for squared, *not* for non-squared distances.

Comment: very clear, thank youuu

Answer (score 0):

K-means minimizes the sums of squares.

The sum of squares is the *squared* Euclidean distance.

Because of this, Matlab kmeans also uses squared Euclidean distances.

So if you want to return the cluster assignment and the non-squared Euclidean distances, you can reuse the earlier squared deviations, and only need to compute the square root each.